# Efficient data structure used to store and retrieve information

Tags: python

Given following information:

```
item : Apple
price : 120

item : Orange
price : 90

item : Banana
price : 60
```

What data structure should be used to store the above data in python. How to get the price of banana using that data structure?

My Approach:
I thought it can be stored using list of dictionary.

```
List = [{'item':'Apple','price':120},{'item':'Orange','price':90},{'item':'Banana','price':60}]

#Retrieving price of banana

for i in range(len(List)):
    if List[i]['item']=='Banana':
        price = List[i]['price']
        print(price)
```

What is wrong with the above approach? Or is there any better approach for the above problem?

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a *list* here; you can store all your items in *one* dictionary, mapping item name to price:

```
item_prices = {
    'Apple': 120,
    'Orange': 90,
    'Banana': 60,
}

print(item_prices['Banana'])
```

Now you don't need a loop anymore. And testing if an item is present is as easy as `if 'Banana' in item_prices:`, no full scan required.